# python django 404 error

Tags: python, django

i am learning python django.but i am getting this error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in x.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^y/

The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

i really don't know why i am getting this error
first i created django project like:

```
   django-admin startproject x
```

then i got these files:

```
   db.sqlite3  manage.py  x
```

then i created app like:

```
   python manage.py startapp y
```

then i got these files:

```
   db.sqlite3  manage.py  x  y
```

then i edited urls.py in my x folder and included the file that i created in y folder the code is
my urls.py file in x folder

```
  from django.conf.urls import include, url
  from django.contrib import admin

  urlpatterns = [
              url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
              url(r'^y/',include('y.urls'))
  ]
```

my urls.py file in y folder

```
  from django.conf.urls import url
  from . import views

  urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^$/', views.index, name = 'index'),

  ]
```

my view.py file from folder y is

```
     from django.http import HttpResponse


     def index(request):
                return HttpResponse("<h1>hello sir</h1>")
```

when i starts it in terminal its starts well:

```
     python manage.py runserver
     Performing system checks...

     System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
     August 19, 2017 - 17:32:10
     Django version 1.11.4, using settings 'x.settings'
     Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
     Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

these are extra information just i downloaded pycharm to compile and run python
there i tested my above files those are y/urls.py x/urls.py

when i compiled y/urls.py file i got this error:

```
  /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/peter/Desktop/x/x/urls.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peter/Desktop/x/x/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 280, in urls
   return self.get_urls(), 'admin', self.name
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 238, in get_urls
   from django.contrib.contenttypes import views as contenttype_views
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/contenttypes/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 139, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 140, in ContentType
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1061, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
     self._setup(name)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

   Process finished with exit code 1
```

and got this error when i compiled x/urls.py file:

```
  /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/peter/Desktop/x/x/urls.py
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/peter/Desktop/x/x/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 280, in urls
   return self.get_urls(), 'admin', self.name
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 238, in get_urls
   from django.contrib.contenttypes import views as contenttype_views
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/contenttypes/views.py", line 5, in <module>
   from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 139, in <module>
   class ContentType(models.Model):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 140, in ContentType
   app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1061, in __init__
   super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
   self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
   self._setup(name)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
   % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

   Process finished with exit code 1
```

i also compiled views.py and setting.py but they successfully compiled without any errors but got error only in x/urls.py and y/urls.py file please help me
but when i opens web browser i got error.

i just wanted to print hello sir on my web browser but got this error don't know why.and i am using updated version of firefox i tried this in latest version of chrome too but don't know why please help me,please teach me how to fix this

i learning programe all by myself with the help of internet so please help me to fix this error
sorry my english is bad please don't mind for grammitcal error please help me
please...

please help me,please teach me how to fix this error

Comment: try this url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/y// because you have prefixed your app's (y) urls with '/y/' in the urls.py (under project (x) folder) btw, try to give meaningful names to your project and applications.

Comment: tried it but don't know got this error

Comment: error:
Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/y/

Using the URLconf defined in x.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/
    ^y/ ^$/ [name='index']

The current path, y/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: How about doing what the error message says? _either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings_

Comment: You aren't meant to run the urls files directly (`python2.7 /home/peter/Desktop/x/x/urls.py`), so don't worry about those errors.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the slash from `r'^$/'`. The dollar `$` means end of string, so if you add anything after it, then you'll never get a match.

Then, you should try `127.0.0.1:8000/y/` in your browser. You haven't defined a pattern for `^$` in your project's urls, so `127.0.0.1:8000/` isn't going to work.

Comment: thank you.i removed dollar sign and it worked thank you very much alasdair